# Infinite Loop with While inside Foreach and MySQL

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, mysqli, while-loop

I'm having a very odd problem with PHP/MySQL...

**echos "id;id"**

```
 foreach($ids as $id) {
      echo "id;";
 }
```

**echos "id;id;id;id;..." (infinite loop)**

```
 foreach($ids as $id) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `id`=$id;") {
           echo "id;";
      }
 }
```

The reason I have a foreach() statement is because I have $ids sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *will* get an infinite loop, simply because you run the query anew every single time through the `while` loop. That means, for each `$id`, you continuously run the query and extract the first row from it. So, for any query that returns more than zero rows, the continual re-execution of that query will make the `while` loop endless.

It's functionally similar in effect to the following pseudo-code, which will also loop forever since you're modifying the control condition within the loop:

```
loop i from 1 to 10
    set i to 1
endloop
```

You should instead try something like:

```
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `id`=$id;");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo "id;";
    }
}
```

This will run the query *once* for each ID and the `while` loop will process the rows for that query.

Comment: There's only two values in $ids, so why is it running the query more than twice?

Comment: @rtainc, the infinite loop is the `while`, not the `foreach`. I'll clarify.

Comment: @rtainc, relax, I've done _far_ sillier things in my long career, none of which I'll admit to here :-)